# What are Java interfaces useful for and how to deal with cross-class methods?

Tags: java, methods, interface, code-injection

I understand that Java Interfaces are used for declaring methods that will be used in more classes as those classes implement them. For example:

```
public interface MyInterface{

   void myVoidMethod();  
   Bool myBoolMethod(int x);  
   String myStringMethod(String a,String b);

}
```

So, from what I understand, it is mainly used just to make sure some methods are declared in  a class and those methods are usually ones that are more general, and might be applied in more classes. But what about methods that should already contain some code and should apply to more classes?
 For example what if I have many classes where I need `myBoolMethod` defined as

`Bool myBoolMethod(int x){

  return x?0:1;}`
(I gave just a simple example, but obviously I would need to use more complex methods). I've heard about "code injection" and I'm pretty sure it's related to it, but I have no clue how to go further, neither do I know what to do not to rewrite the same code in different places.

Comment: In this case look at abstract classes - but better find a Java tutorial/book a good one will explain all this

Comment: Note that in Java 8 an interface can provide a default implementation for its methods. *However*, that's *mainly* meant to be able to extend interfaces after they've been introduced. It's *not* generally a good idea to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily. It is also used for testing. If you don't have an interface you can't provide a custom implementation for your testing purposes. Another concern might be the "code to interfaces not implementations" paradigm. Let me illustrate:

Suppose you have an `ArrayList` of Strings:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

You use this in your code but later you later find out that you'll need a `LinkedList` because it is more efficient for your problem.

What happens now? You have to refactor your code in many places.
However if you've used the `List` interface in the first place you could've passed it around without caring about the implementation of it so if you later find out that you need a `LinkedList` instead of an `ArrayList` you just have to modify in a single place:

```
List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
```

If you need cross-class methods you can create an `abstract` class and provide a default implementation for a method defined in your `interface`. It will be shared in all your implementing classes in case you don't override it.

Comment: Ok, so it the case of an `abstract` class implementing an `interface`, I would then extend other classes with the `abstract` class, as it is already implementing the interface, so my subclasses would already inherit the methods defined in the interface and the implementation from the abstract class, right?

Comment: Your abstract class can implement an interface and your concrete implementations can extend your abstract class. Your abstract class doesn't have to implement all (or any) methods of the interface. Although it does not make sense to have an empty abstract class.

Comment: I understand this, but the abstract class should contain the implementations of the interface and then other classes should extend my abstract class, from what I understand. Is this right?

Comment: In most cases yes. Although there may be some situations where you don't want to implement all methods since you know that for example there is a method which will have different implementations in **every** derived class.

Answer (score 1):

With java 7, you would have to use an abstract class to provide a default implementation for a method. There is no way to define some behaviours of your object in an interface.

With java 8 you would be able to provide a default implementation for a method in an interface.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to ensure that classes have certain methods that already have implementations, then you want to be using an [Abstract Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html).

An Interface is simply a contract, that stipulates when a class agrees to implement that interface, it MUST provide an implementation for those methods. This is useful when you want to encourage loose coupling in your code, by having objects refer to your class via an interface, rather than via the object's direct methods.

Comment: Can abstract classes be implemented alike interfaces?

Comment: No. You use the "extends" keyword for abstract classes. A class inherits all the methods specified in an abstract class.

Comment: But it is worth mentioning that if you have abstract methods (methods you would find in an interface) inside an abstract class, then a subclass will have to provide an implementation for that code; much like an interface in that respect. These methods are called "abstract methods".

Comment: So my class would inherit all the methods and variables from the abstract class, won't they?

Comment: Correct. And if you specified any abstract methods in the abstract class, then you will also need to provide implementations for them.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for abstract classes and inheritance.
More info on inheritance and using the `super` keyword here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html

Comment: So the idea would be to extend an abstract class>

Comment: Or just a class if you wish to be able to make instances of the super class. Note: if you look at the menu on the left you can see info on abstract classes here too.

Comment: The abstract class seems to be what I was looking for, thank you

Answer (score 1):

An interface is useful (speaking from practical experience) where you want to specify that a certain variable/parameter should conform to the **contract** some other posters mention, and nothing extra. E.g. you have a resource that gets injected (say a data source) but you don't want to specify yet whether it should be a connection to a say MySQL DB, a SQL Server DB, or a dummy data source that you are going to use just for testing without affecting live data. So you specify the type as the interface type, and at runtime an instance of the appropriate implementing type gets injected. You could google for some injection (CDI) tutorials if you are interested.

In other cases you would rather want to use a superclass (abstract or not). The correct answer is: it depends, and one would do good to read (and then review) theory and books on Java language fundamentals to be able to make the best choice for your particular circumstances.